# While running react-native project in android Emulator am getting error as 'Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest''

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio-2.0

**Here is my AndroidManifest.xml code and androidStudio log image**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed something in the AndroidManifest ? cause the code said that you screwed the code's permission

Did you used an API ?

Comment: No i just added the contents for react-native-pushnotifications.then i got these errors

Comment: did you save your module  : $ npm i --save react-native-puch-notification ?     and did you follow to full instruction to setup the module with your project